# Structs and pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a few questions about structs and pointers

For this struct:

```
typedef struct tNode_t {
    char *w;
} tNode;
```

How come if I want to change/know the value of *w I need to use `t.w = "asdfsd"` instead 
of `t->w = "asdfasd"`?

And I compiled this successfully without having `t.w = (char *) malloc(28*sizeof(char));`
in my testing code, is there a reason why tt's not needed?

Sample main:

```
int main()
{
    tNode t;
    char w[] = "abcd";
    //t.word = (char *) malloc(28*sizeof(char));
    t.word = w;
    printf("%s", t.word);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: it compiles because you have a local copy already defined, no need to dynamically create it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`t->w` is shorthand for `(*t).w` i.e. it only makes sense to use the arrow if `t` is a pointer to a struct.

Also, since the string you assigned is hard-coded (thus, determined at compile time), there's no need to dynamically allocate its memory at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this tutorial: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/ch5x.htm

```
struct tag {
char lname[20];      /* last name */
char fname[20];      /* first name */
int age;             /* age */
float rate;          /* e.g. 12.75 per hour */
};
```

kay, so we know that our pointer is going to point to a structure declared using struct tag. We declare such a pointer with the declaration:

```
struct tag *st_ptr;
```

and we point it to our example structure with:

```
st_ptr = &my_struct;
```

Now, we can access a given member by de-referencing the pointer. But, how do we de-reference the pointer to a structure? Well, consider the fact that we might want to use the pointer to set the age of the employee. We would write:

```
(*st_ptr).age = 63;
```

Look at this carefully. It says, replace that within the parenthesis with that which st_ptr points to, which is the structure my_struct. Thus, this breaks down to the same as my_struct.age.

However, this is a fairly often used expression and the designers of C have created an alternate syntax with the same meaning which is:

```
st_ptr->age = 63;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How come if I want to change/know the value of *w I need to use t.w =
>   "asdfsd" instead of t->w = "asdfasd"?

If your `t` is a pointer, you need to use `t->w`. Else you should use `t.w`.

> in my testing code, is there a reason why tt's not needed?

In your code you have already set your `t.word` to point to the area storing your `char w[] = "abcd";`. So you don't need to `malloc` some memory for your `t.word`.

Another example where `malloc` is needed is:

```
tNode t;
t.word = (char *) malloc(28*sizeof(char));
strcpy(t.word, "Hello World");
printf("%s", t.word);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How come if I want to change/know the value of *w I need to use t.w =
>   "asdfsd" instead of t->w = "asdfasd"?

`t` is a `tNode`, not a pointer to `tNode`, so `.` is the appropriate accessor.

> And I compiled this successfully without having t.w = (char *)
>   malloc(28*sizeof(char)); in my testing code, is there a reason why
>   tt's not needed?

This isn't needed because `"abcd"` is still in scope so `w` can just point to it. If you want `w` to point to persistent memory-managed contents, it will have to allocate its own memory as it would with this line.